# SBC electric choke issue

Tags: chevrolet, choke, sbc, c10

I have a 1969 Chevrolet C10 1/2 ton pickup with stock 350 small block engine. Don’t know much about internals of engine as I purchased the truck with engine in it and not much info. Had a Quadra jet carb that was leaking and I put a 600 Holley with electric choke. Starts good with pressing throttle once and choke sets and goes through step down as it should and runs good. My question is should the choke activate after engine sets for 30-45 minutes. It seems to take forever cranking over after warmup to start without touching throttle. If you press throttle or pump it then the choke sets again no matter what ambient temp is. I know it hasn’t cooled off enough to need choke again so I don’t know if I’m doing something wrong or if it could be a setting issue. Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!